# Print out the second byte in printf() in one single line

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, printf, memory-address

How can i print out the second byte in a stored integer in one line on printf as shown in
in the second printf()

```c
unsigned int aNum = 258; // 4 bytes in allocated memory
unsigned char * newP = &aNum;

printf("\n with a pre-created pointer %02i",newP[1]); //getting the second byte[02]
printf("\n address without a pre-created pointer %02i",(unsigned char)aNum); // getting the first byte[01]
```

Comment: That is great , thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be better to use bitwise operators:

```
unsigned num = ...
unsigned char lowest_byte = num & 0xFF;
unsigned char second_low_byte = ((num & 0xFF00) >> 8);
printf ("\nfirst byte: %02i, second byte: %02i\n", (unsigned) lowest_byte, (unsigned)second_low_byte);
```

You don't really need temporary variables of course, you can do the bitwise operations directly in `printf` operands.

---

If you absolutely need to use an array, then this is the way:

```
unsigned char *ptr = (unsigned char*)&num;
printf ("\nfirst byte: %02x, second byte: %02x\n", ptr[0], ptr[1]);
```

Comment: Aren't also you using temporaries?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès yes, that's why I called out that it's not necessary. Just for convenience.

Comment: this was great  @littleadv

Comment: Note: The two snippets give the same output on a little-endian machine, but different output on a big-endian machine (where low is last, not first).

Comment: @ikegami that is correct, and that is why the first way is the right way.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this solution:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned int aNum = 0x1a2b3c4du; // 4 bytes in allocated memory

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        printf("\nbyte %d  %02x", i, (unsigned int) ((unsigned char *) &aNum)[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, this prints all bytes of the instead of only second,  just replace `[i]` with `2` and you get it.